# Entity Framework, how to work with not mapped entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I've got a doubt about working with not mapped POCO entities.
I have an Entity that contains properties(and this properties are other POCO classes that are mapped to the database).

I've got a generic repository where this repository receives an generic entity to work with:

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal readonly DbContext recuperadorContext;
    internal readonly IDbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        recuperadorContext = context;
        dbSet = recuperadorContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public TEntity Adicionar(TEntity obj)
    {
        var objReturn = dbSet.Add(obj);
        return objReturn;
    }
```

}

The implementation is:

```
public class CupomFiscalRepository : BaseRepository<CupomFiscalDetalhes> 
{
}
```

The not mapped entity with it's properties is described bellow:

```
public class CupomFiscalDetalhes
{
    public Movimento Movimento { get; set; } //POCO class mapped
    public Cliente ClienteCRM { get; set; } //POCO class mapped
    public Vendedor Vendedor { get; set; } //POCO class mapped
}
```

Since CupomFiscalDetalhes does not have a table to be mapped, do I need to have all the POCO classes mapped in EntityFramework to work with ht?
Asking because I don't know how I'm going to save these data to the database with the generic repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to persist CupomFiscalDetalhes then you should add it to the context.
If you don't need to persist CupomFiscalDetalhes then it shouldn't implement IBaseRepository and you should consider it a view of data populated via a controller class.

Comment: Thanks for the help @robaudas so, even that CupomFiscalDetalhes has some properties(other classes that has a related table ), only those classes gonna implement the IBaseRepository to be persisted, and CupomFiscalDetalhes is going to be a class that "joins" the bunch of informations, right?

Comment: That sounds like what you are trying to do. Some controller class will search the repositories for the 3 related entities then assign them to the class properties.